# PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor vs JpaVendorAdapter

Tags: spring, hibernate, persistence

I'm setting up a maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-tomcat environment.

I would like to inject my Entity manager using the @PersistenceContext annotation.
As I understand to do this, I should have PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor defined in my application context, pointing to my persistence.xml file.

In this case my application context could be looking like this more or less:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:ox="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <!-- Context -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yl.mypack" />

    <!-- AOP -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <!-- Properties -->

    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:db.connection.properties,applicationProperties.properties" />

    <!-- DB Connection Pool -->
    <bean id="dataSourceGlobal" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">

        <!-- Data Source -->
        <property name="driverClass" value="${driverClass}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbcUrl}" />
        <property name="user" value="${user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />

        <!-- C3P0 Connection pool properties -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${c3p0.min_pool_size}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${c3p0.max_pool_size}" />
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="${c3p0.timeout}" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${c3p0.idle_test_period}" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="${c3p0.max_statements}" />
        <property name="automaticTestTable" value="${c3p0.automatic_test_table}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- JPA -->
    <!-- Creates a EntityManagerFactory for use with the Hibernate JPA provider -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceGlobal" />
    </bean>



    <!-- In order to enable EntityManager injection -->
    <bean id="persistenceAnnotation"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="persistenceUnits">
            <map>
                <entry key="myPU" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceGlobal" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My persistence.xml could look like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"
            value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

So now I guess I should be able to inject my entity manager using the @PersistenceContext annotation, at list this is what I get from the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html). Before I'mm getting to JpaVendorAdapter, my first question would refer the entity manager factory definition:
The following properties:

```
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />
```

Are these required to be referred from the entity manager factory? Is it a must?

My second question would be regarding the JpaVendorAdapter, and in my case [HibernateJpaVendorAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.html).

If I use HibernateJpaVendorAdapter, do I still need to have a persistence.xml file? Since some of the properties are overlapping. Moreover, do I still need to have PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor defined, pointing to my persistence.xml file? Can these 2 go together (PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor and HibernateJpaVendorAdapter)? Should they go together? What is the best practice, assuming I'm **avoiding** any JDNI style definitions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: At least since Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE, when using annotation-driven Javaconfig, the Spring container automatically creates a `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. [That's what](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) [the documentation says](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight). Therefore, you as a user of a Spring container don't need to explicitly create a `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of data source bean and HibernateJpaVendorAdapter allows you to get rid of persistence.xml with Spring 3.1. Check out this article:

http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/13/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-3-1-and-jpa/

So the answers:

1. They are not a must.
2. No, you don't need to have a persistence.xml.
3. I am not exactly sure of what use PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is.

   ```
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.dao" />
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hibernate-resourceLocal"/>
   </bean>

   <tx:annotation-driven/>

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
       <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
   </bean>
   ```

My Spring application context xml looks as simple as this. And it is working.

I don't what the best practice is, but I will keep persistence.xml so that in case I need to expose my service as session bean, it can be easily done.